# How do I find my ftp credentials on my free wordpress site?

Tags: wordpress, ftp, filezilla

I want to download my files via filezilla and upload to github, but I cannot find my ftp credentials anywhere in the wordpress admin. I created the site on wordpress and have done nothing with hosting thus far.

Answer (score 3):

Read https://en.support.wordpress.com/ftp-access/ at wordpress.com

> We do not allow FTP (File Transfer Protocol) access to any
>   WordPress.com blogs.

See the link above for alternatives to using FTP with .com sites.

Also, read https://en.support.wordpress.com/com-vs-org/ for the differences between .com and self-hosted .org sites. You may find you want to self-host a WordPress site in order to use more capabilities of WordPress beyond the free .com version.